# Database consistency errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dbcc, consistency

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and one of my databases has loads of consistency errors. When I try to query a particular record from a table it displays an error message similar to this

```
Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 4
SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: torn page (expected signature: 0x00000000; actual signature: 0x04100410). It occurred during a read of page (1:2052727) in database ID 7 at offset 0x000003ea4ee000 in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL\BV4.mdf'.
```

When I run DBCC CHECK DB I get the following information

```
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (0:285483064). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 7 partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (0:333637984). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (0:347758808). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (0:354328536). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page (0:354781272). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -1.
Msg 8909, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 0 (type Unknown), page ID (1:1977873) contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = (0:356303736).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 60 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383462) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Page (1:9383462) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:9365636) and previous (1:9383461) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383463) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 284 refers to child page (1:9383463) and previous child (1:9383462), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383464) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 285 refers to child page (1:9383464) and previous child (1:9383463), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383465) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 286 refers to child page (1:9383465) and previous child (1:9383464), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383466) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 287 refers to child page (1:9383466) and previous child (1:9383465), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383467) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 288 refers to child page (1:9383467) and previous child (1:9383466), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383468) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 289 refers to child page (1:9383468) and previous child (1:9383467), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383469) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 290 refers to child page (1:9383469) and previous child (1:9383468), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383470) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). 
Index node page (1:9365636), slot 291 refers to child page (1:9383470) and previous child (1:9383469), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data): Page (1:9383471) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:9365636), slot 292 refers to child page (1:9383471) and previous child (1:9383470), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 158623608, index ID 8, partition ID 72057594349813760, alloc unit ID 72057594951303168 (type In-row data). Page (1:9383472) is missing a reference from previous page (1:9383471). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 21 consistency errors in table 'ContactHistory' (object ID 158623608).
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 206623779, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594350010368, alloc unit ID 72057594951499776 (type In-row data): Page (1:9681196) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 206623779, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594350010368, alloc unit ID 72057594951499776 (type In-row data). Page (1:9681196) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:9680832) and previous (1:9681195) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 206623779, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594350010368, alloc unit ID 72057594951499776 (type In-row data): Page (1:9681197) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 206623779, index ID 3, partition ID 72057594350075904, alloc unit ID 72057594951565312 (type In-row data). Page (1:2140777) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:2543702) and previous (1:8408623) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 206623779, index ID 3, partition ID 72057594350075904, alloc unit ID 72057594951565312 (type In-row data). Page (1:8408622) is missing a reference from previous page (1:2140777). Possible chain linkage problem.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 206623779, index ID 3, partition ID 72057594350075904, alloc unit ID 72057594951565312 (type In-row data). Page (1:8530728) is missing a reference from previous page (1:2140776). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 18 consistency errors in table 'ContactData' (object ID 206623779).
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 658101385, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594045333504, alloc unit ID 72057594048937984 (type In-row data): Page (1:1975515) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 658101385, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594045333504, alloc unit ID 72057594048937984 (type In-row data). Page (1:1975515) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:1980843) and previous (1:1975514) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 658101385, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594045333504, alloc unit ID 72057594048937984 (type In-row data): Page (1:1981605) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 658101385, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594045333504, alloc unit ID 72057594048937984 (type In-row data): Page (1:2140775) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 658101385, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594045333504, alloc unit ID 72057594048937984 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:2142374), slot 258 refers to child page (1:2140775) and previous child (1:2140774), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 658101385, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594045333504, alloc unit ID 72057594048937984 (type In-row data). Page (1:2141016) is missing a reference from previous page (1:2140775). Possible chain linkage problem.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 658101385, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594045399040, alloc unit ID 72057594049003520 (type In-row data). Page (1:1180333) is missing a reference from previous page (1:2052728). Possible chain linkage problem.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 658101385, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594045399040, alloc unit ID 72057594049003520 (type In-row data): Page (1:2052728) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 658101385, index ID 2, partition ID 72057594045399040, alloc unit ID 72057594049003520 (type In-row data). Page (1:2052728) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:2625714) and previous (1:604367) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 40 consistency errors in table 'CallTransaction_Hist' (object ID 658101385).
Msg 8993, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 1549248574, forwarding row page (1:1043918), slot 41 points to page (1:1981608), slot 14. Did not encounter forwarded row. Possible allocation error.
Msg 8993, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 1549248574, forwarding row page (1:1753548), slot 41 points to page (1:1981608), slot 13. Did not encounter forwarded row. Possible allocation error.
Msg 8993, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 1549248574, forwarding row page (1:1950913), slot 4 points to page (1:1981608), slot 0. Did not encounter forwarded row. Possible allocation error.
Msg 8993, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 1549248574, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594055557120, alloc unit ID 72057594060996608 (type In-row data): Page (1:2976311) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8994, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 1549248574, forwarded row page (1:2976569), slot 8 should be pointed to by forwarding row page (1:2976310), slot 6. Did not encounter forwarding row. Possible allocation error.
Msg 8994, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 1549248574, forwarded row page (1:2976585), slot 24 should be pointed to by forwarding row page (1:2976311), slot 23. Did not encounter forwarding row. Possible allocation error.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 51 consistency errors in table 'MitelSMDRFields' (object ID 1549248574).
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2101582525, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594043891712, alloc unit ID 72057594046971904 (type In-row data): Page (1:1977873) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2101582525, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594043891712, alloc unit ID 72057594046971904 (type In-row data): Page (1:2976380) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 8 consistency errors in table 'CallRecords_Hist' (object ID 2101582525).
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data): Page (1:1894807) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data). Page (1:1894807) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:1926658) and previous (1:1894806) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data). Page (1:1896440) is missing a reference from previous page (1:1894807). Possible chain linkage problem.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data): Page (1:1981592) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data), page (1:1981592). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -4.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data). Page (1:1981592) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:1747297) and previous (1:1979391) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data): Page (1:1981593) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:1747297), slot 45 refers to child page (1:1981593) and previous child (1:1981592), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data): Page (1:1981594) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:1747297), slot 46 refers to child page (1:1981594) and previous child (1:1981593), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data): Page (1:1981595) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:1747297), slot 47 refers to child page (1:1981595) and previous child (1:1981594), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data): Page (1:1981596) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594349617152, alloc unit ID 72057594951106560 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:1747297), slot 48 refers to child page (1:1981596) and previous child (1:1981595), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 4, partition ID 72057594350600192, alloc unit ID 72057594952155136 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:1742162), slot 166 refers to child page (1:1977863) and previous child (1:1977862), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2114106572, index ID 4, partition ID 72057594350600192, alloc unit ID 72057594952155136 (type In-row data). Page (1:1986864) is missing a reference from previous page (1:1977863). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 32 consistency errors in table 'AgentHistory' (object ID 2114106572).
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2129442660, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594095730688, alloc unit ID 72057594148421632 (type In-row data): Page (1:1894506) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8993, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2129442660, forwarding row page (1:2142034), slot 62 points to page (1:2142059), slot 36. Did not encounter forwarded row. Possible allocation error.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Object ID 2129442660, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594095730688, alloc unit ID 72057594148421632 (type In-row data): Page (1:2142055) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 7
Table error: Object ID 2129442660, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594095730688, alloc unit ID 72057594148421632 (type In-row data), page (1:2142055). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -4.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 9 consistency errors in table 'Contact_Map' (object ID 2129442660).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 239 consistency errors in database 'DBV4'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (DBV4).
```

Could you please help me figure out the solution as I don't want to use repair_allow_data_loss as the data is very critical

Comment: Do you have any backups available?

Comment: @George.Palacios There are no clean backups, since the database was in a simple recovery model. I have been asked to try and repair the data

Comment: Start here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/dbcc-checkdb-reports-corruption/

Comment: @user1587600, did you ran this command "DBCC CheckDB (<database name> WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS; " to see advice from command.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan yes that is what i had run and received the above results

Comment: @user1587600, you only run the query " DBCC CHECKDB('Databasename');" you didn' run  this query DBCC CheckDB (<database name> WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS; as you said in your question.

Comment: As I can see it is a lot on indexes, you can fix them by recreating them. Also check your storage for corruption!

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan i did run the DBCC CheckDB (<database name> WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS; i forgot to mention the remaining command in the question

Comment: I would start by scripting the indexes in question from the above objects, removing them, then rerunning the CHECKDB

Comment: @StijnWynants there are several where index ID is 0 or 1. If the table or clustered index is corrupt, what are you going to recreate the indexes from?

Comment: Then it is not possible. Just mentioning if it is not on those ones and just on the others you can

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any answer given now is unlikely to help OP.